# GKMatch - Real time - invite handler

Tags: ios, game-center, gkmatchmaker

I am trying to create a real time multiplayer game using game center, programatically. My problem is the lack of documentation since the old `inviteHandler` has been deprecated.

The first thing I do is the authentication:

```
- (void) authenticateLocalPlayer
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    __weak GKLocalPlayer *blockLocalPlayer = localPlayer;
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *receivedViewController, NSError *error)
    {
        if (receivedViewController != nil)
        {
            [self presentViewController:receivedViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else if (blockLocalPlayer.isAuthenticated)
        {
            [blockLocalPlayer registerListener:self];
        }
    };
}
```

After that, I start the invitation process as it says on apple docs.

```
- (void)invitePlayers:(NSArray *)friendsArray
{
    GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
    request.minPlayers = 2;
    request.maxPlayers = 2;
    request.playersToInvite = friendsArray;
    request.inviteMessage = @"Your Custom Invitation Message Here";
    request.inviteeResponseHandler = ^(NSString *playerID, GKInviteeResponse response)
    {
        [self updateUIForPlayer: playerID accepted: (response == GKInviteeResponseAccepted)];
    };
}
```

I implemented the following methods, but they are never called:

```
- (void)player:(GKPlayer *)player didAcceptInvite:(GKInvite *)invite
- (void)player:(GKPlayer *)player didRequestMatchWithPlayers:(NSArray *)playerIDsToInvite
```

How can I let the other player receive the invite and respond to it? On the apple docs the old deprecated way is demonstrated.

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567104/gkmatchmaker-invite-handler-deprecated) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904588/gamekit-gkmatchmaker-invitehandler-deprecated-in-ios7-what-is-the-replacement).

Answer (score 0):

Try to register first for a `GKLocalPlayer` listener in order to get called via this methods:

```
- (void)registerListener:(id<GKLocalPlayerListener>)listener
```

which should conforms to this protocol:`GKLocalPlayerListener`